# iPad mini Smart Case problem - Sleep when folding over the back

Tags: ipad

I just got an iPad mini with Retina Display (from the Apple Store) and a Smart Case.

The problem I'm having is that when folding the smart case over the back, the magnets of the Case would put the iPad to sleep.

I'm headed to the Apple Store today, but wanted to know if anyone else had experienced something like this, and if so, if was the iPad's or case's fault.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Amazon products

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about non-official Apple products.

Comment: The case was purchased at Apple but is a legitimate Apple Smart Case. It's irrelevant to the question where I purchased it. I should edit it, but it is on topic.

Comment: @Rob & Buscar웃 FYI Regardless of purchase origin, [Smart Case](http://tinyurl.com/msj82le) appears to be an official Apple Product. Furthermore, [If you have a question about… **third-party hardware,** services and software when **associated for use with Apple products...** then you're in the right place to ask your question!](http://apple.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As good as industrial manufacturing is these days, there are always variances. Chances are the magnet in your Smart Case is a bit stronger than Apple intended. You can either wait for the magnet to lose some of its magnetism, go to an Apple Store and have them replace it for you, or try holding your Smart Case a little differently as illustrated below.

[image: smart case 1]

[image: smart case 2]

[image: smart case 3]